# Aggregation over a specific partition in Apache Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Lets say I have a Kafka topic named `SensorData` to which two sensors S1 and S2 are sending data (timestamp and value) to two different partitions e.g. S1 -> P1 and S2 -> P2. Now I need to aggregate the values for these two sensors separately, lets say calculating the average sensor value over a time window of 1 hour and writing it into a new topic `SensorData1Hour`. With this scenario

1. How can I select a specific topic partition using the `KStreamBuilder#stream` method?
2. Is it possible to apply some aggregation function over two (multiple) different partitions from same topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot (directly) access single partitions and you cannot (directly) apply an aggregation function over multiple partitions.

Aggregations are always done per `key`: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#stateful-transformations

1. Thus, you could use a different key for each partition and than aggregate by key. See http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#windowing-a-stream

The simplest way is to let each of your producers apply a key to each message right away.

2. If you want to aggregate multiple partitions, you first need to set a new key (e.g., using `selectKey()`) and set the same key for all data you want to aggregate (if you want to aggregate all partitions, you would use a single key value -- however, keep in mind, this might quickly become a bottleneck!).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this one. Is there any starter code example available for aggregateByKey?

Comment: http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html#code-examples

Comment: @Samy Did this answer your question? If yes, feel free to accept and/or upvote.